# How to correctly get file path using QUrl on windows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt6

So need to allow users to select a file path via QT application.
For this I use [getOpenFileUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl).

Then I take the resulting [QUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QUrl.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QUrl.path) and ask for it as `path` which returns a string.
However, when I convert this to a python native `pathlib.path` I get that the path does not exists. The path it result in is: `\C:\Users\LNI\Desktop\test_qt_dialog_picker\main.py`

See code below:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog

import sys
import pathlib

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        selection_result = QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(self, 'Select a File')
        path = selection_result[0].path()
        print(f'Path as "path": {path}')
        path = pathlib.Path(path)
        print(f'Path as pathlib path: {path}')
        print(f'Path exists: {path.exists()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow(None)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Now if I instead use the QUrl `toString()` I get a different problem because this is prepended with `file:///` (which makes sense) and this is by pathlib is translated to `file:\C:\Users\LNI\Desktop\test_qt_dialog_picker\main.py` see the code below:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog

import sys
import pathlib

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        selection_result = QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(self, 'Select a File')
        path = selection_result[0].toString()
        print(f'Path as str: {path}')
        path = pathlib.Path(path)
        print(f'Path as pathlib path: {path}')
        print(f'Path exists: {path.exists()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow(None)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Now I can fix this by adding, an `if` although this causes issues on linux but I can handle that easy:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog

import sys
import pathlib

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        selection_result = QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(self, 'Select a File')
        path = selection_result[0].path()
        print(f'Path as "path": {path}')
        if path.startswith('/') and len(path) > 1:
            path = path[1:]
        path = pathlib.Path(path)
        print(f'Path as pathlib path: {path}')
        print(f'Path exists: {path.exists()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow(None)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

But is this really the best option on windows? Is there a better alternative or am I doing the only option? I am also wondering if the `/` at the beginning of the path on Windows is a bug in QT.

Comment: Use toLocalFile() method

Comment: Do not use `getOpenFileUrl` - use [`getOpenFileName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) instead.